# reactjs onClick function responds with one step delay

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a function which helps me to fill an array and compare the elements. however, when I do a console.log on the filled array it shows me the result with a late step. how can i solve this problem? thank you for helping me.

```
const handleIdem = (table) => {
  let idem = false
  let dataT = []
  table.map((item) => {
    listId.includes(item.id) && dataT.push(item.MONTANT_PAIEMENT)
  })
  // Vérifier si tous les éléments du tableau sont identiques
  if (dataT.every((val, i, arr) => val === arr[0]) == true) {
    idem = true
  }
  console.log(dataT)
  return idem
}

<TableauBasic
   disableSelectionOnClick={true}
   col={enteteCol}
   donnees={data.infos}
   onSelectionModelChange={(e) => {
      setListId(e)
      handleIdem(data.infos)
   }}
   onRowClick={(e) => {}}
   checkboxSelection={true}
   pagination
   pageSize={150}
 />
```

Comment: Where is your react code?

Comment: I updated the code above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the code is not really clear what are you trying to achieve since we don't see `setListId` and `data`. I suppose you have something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/LordSebastian/0xhar3sk/

You can clean the code to this much more readable format:

https://jsfiddle.net/LordSebastian/0xhar3sk/14/

And please share the related code. Problem is maybe going to be updating `listId` from one place that you check from another place at the same time.